# Analyze Phone call data by date

Tags: excel, date

I am trying to us the countifs function to use different criteria to count phone data on a certain date.
1)if the date is equal to 1/30/2014 then use the data to do the following
2) if the time is between 7:00 and 8:00 then count it.

So my final data would give me Date and number of phone calls between 7 and 8 am.

Here is my initial formula, but it keeps giving me an error.

```
    countIFs('callLog_2014-01-30_2014-01-30'!F2:F63,"1/30/2014",SUMPRODUCT(--MOD('callLog_2014-01-30_2014-01-30'!$F$2:$F$63,1)>=A2),--(MOD('callLog_2014-01-30_2014-01-30'!$F$2:$F$63,1)<=A3)))
```

E2:E63=dates

F2:F63=times

A2=7:00

A3=8:00

What I want to end up with

7:00  2 calls

8:00 4 calls

9:00 8 calls
etc.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the text string "1/30/2014" Excel treats that as text, not as a date to compare your date values to. I would recommend putting the date 1/30/2014 into a cell somewhere, say A1.

> What I want to end up with
>
> 7:00 2 calls
>
> 8:00 4 calls
>
> 9:00 8 calls etc.

I'm taking this to mean that A2 has 7:00, A3 has 8:00, A4 has 9:00, etc.

Formula syntax then would be:

=COUNTIFS('allLog_2014-01-30_2014-01-30'!$E$2:$E$63,$A$1,'allLog_2014-01-30_2014-01-30'!$F$2:$F$63,">="&A2,'allLog_2014-01-30_2014-01-30'!$F$2:$F$63,"<"&A3)